# Converting a text file with one column to multiple column

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I have a file with data in one column format. I need to use this file as an input file and the output file should be in a multi column format. I need help with a script that will do the conversion. It does not matter PowerShell or batch.

Input file content:input.txt

store1:
apple
orange
peach
**THE END**

store2:
Tree
Park
Pond
Bird
**THE END**

store3:
Building
Road
peach
store
Grocery
**THE END**

The output file should be:
store1:,store2:,store3:
apple,  Tree,   Building
orange, Park,   Road
peach,  Pond,   peach
,   Bird,   store
,   ,   Grocery

Comment: Oh, cool!  How much does this project pay?  (In other words, what have you tried?  Show some code.  Where are you stuck?)

Comment: 1. I suppose you mean Windows rather than DOS, right? 2. what should the delimiter look like -- `,` or `, ` (`,` followed by _space_)? 3. does text `THE END` occur in the file literally, or does the empty line indicate the next section, or is `store?:` more important?

Comment: We are a community helping programmers and programming enthusiasts. We are devoting our own personal time. This reads like a code writing request which is not what we are here for. People are paid for those types of jobs. Please pick a language and try something on your. Looking here on SO you will find answer to other questions to get you started. Then, if you get stuck, edit your question with what you have tried and we will help and educate you towards a complete solution.

Comment: 4. is the number of sections fixed?

Comment: Yes, "THE END" actually appears in the file. The number of store is not fixed. The delemeter could be "," or 'TAB'. 
the reason I put it out because I have am new to scripting and have not idea where to begin. I tried putting in array but that didn't work out either. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Google is a good place to begin.

Comment: 5. does always a line `store?:` appear at the beginning of a store/block? 6. what about empty lines: can some appear within a store/block, and if yes, do they need to be ignored or kept?

Answer (score 2):

i know this is a gimmie, but i took it as a learning opportunity for myself, and since i have the code maybe someone else can learn from it

```
$text = gc C:\temp\input.txt
$groups = ($text | out-string) -split 'the end' | ? {$_ -notmatch '^(?:\s+)?$'}
$columns = $groups | % {$_.trim().split("`n")[0]}
$rows = $groups | % {$_.trim().Split("`n").count - 2} | sort -desc | select -f 1

$result = 0..$rows | % {
    $row = $_
    $obj = New-Object psobject
    0..$($columns.Count-1) | % {
        $column = $columns[$_]
        $store = $groups[$_].trim().split("`n")
        $item = $store[$row+1]
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $column.trim() -Value $(if ($item) {$item.trim()})
    }
    $obj
}

$result | epcsv C:\temp\input.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define global settings here:
set "INFILE=input.txt"
set "OUTFILE=output.txt"
set "HEAD=^store[1-9][0-9]*:$"
set "FOOT=^THE END$"
set "DELIM=,"

set /A "COL=0, ROW=0, MAX=0"
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('
    findstr /N /R "^" "%INFILE%"
') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
    if defined HEAD (
        if !COL! EQU 0 set /A "ROW=-1"
        cmd /V /C "echo^(!LINE!"| > nul findstr /R /C:"%HEAD%" ^
            && if !ROW! LSS 0 set /A "COL+=1, ROW=0"
        if defined FOOT (
            cmd /V /C "echo^(!LINE!"| > nul findstr /R /C:"%FOOT%" ^
                && set /A "ROW=-1" || if !COL! GTR 0 if !ROW! GEQ 0 set /A "ROW+=1"
        ) else (
            if !COL! GTR 0 set /A "ROW+=1"
        )
    ) else (
        if defined FOOT (
            if !ROW! EQU 0 set /A "COL+=1"
            cmd /V /C "echo^(!LINE!"| > nul findstr /R /C:"%FOOT%" ^
                && set /A "ROW=0" || set /A "ROW+=1"
        ) else (
            if !COL! EQU 0 set /A "COL=1"
            if defined LINE (
                set /A "ROW+=1"
            ) else (
                if !ROW! GTR 0 set /A "COL+=1"
                set /A "ROW=0"
            )
        )
    )
    if !MAX! LSS !ROW! set /A "MAX=!ROW!"
    for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=;" %%I in ("!COL!;!ROW!;!MAX!") do (
        endlocal
        if %%I GTR 0 if %%J GTR 0 (
            set "COLLECT[%%I_%%J]=%%L"
        )
        set /A "COL=%%I, ROW=%%J, MAX=%%K"
    )
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> "%OUTFILE%" (
    for /L %%J in (1,1,%MAX%) do (
        set "LINE="
        for /L %%I in (1,1,%COL%) do (
            if %%I GTR 1 set "LINE=!LINE!!DELIM!"
            if defined COLLECT[%%I_%%J] (
                set "LINE=!LINE!!COLLECT[%%I_%%J]:*:=!"
            )
        )
        echo(!LINE!
    )
)
endlocal
endlocal
exit /B
```

Basically this script collects the data in an array-like variable `COLLECT[COL_ROW]`, where `COL` and `ROW` denote the column and row indexes, respectively. The code consists of two loops, where the first one walks through the given input file and assigns the line texts to the related array elements. The predefined header and footer strings (or, if both are not provided, any empty lines) control determination of the applicable `COL` and `ROW` indexes. `MAX` holds the greatest row index `ROW`, because the blocks of data might be of different size, for later padding. The second loop enumerates the collected data array, builds a line of text per each column and writes them to the specified output file.

The code section at the beginning marked with a remark `rem` defines the global settings of the script, like the input file (`INFILE`), the output file (`OUTFILE`), the header and the footer (`HEAD` and `FOOT`, respectively; both `findstr`-compatible regular expressions; either or both of them can be empty) and the delimiter (`DELIM`).

This approach has got 4 modes:

1. both header and footer are non-empty:

   - data is collected beginning at the first header string;
   - another header appearing after a footer starts a new data column;
   - everything between a footer and the next header is ignored;
   - a header appearing after another one and before a footer is treated as a normal field;
   - header texts are included in the returned data, footer texts are not;
   - empty lines are kept, meaning they result in an empty field;
2. header is non-empty but footer is empty:

   - data is collected beginning at the first header string;
   - another header starts a new data column;
   - header texts are included in the returned data;
   - empty lines are kept, meaning they result in an empty field;
3. footer is non-empty but header is empty:

   - data is collected beginning at the very first line;
   - a footer starts a new data column;
   - footer texts are not included in the returned data;
   - empty lines are kept, meaning they result in an empty field;
4. both header and footer are empty:

   - data is collected beginning at the first non-empty line;
   - a block of one or more consecutive empty lines starts a new data column;
   - empty lines are not included in the returned data;

---

**Note:**
Although the question lacks of information and attempts of or research by the poster, I decided to answer it, because the task at hand is a quite interesting challenge being solved with a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

---

**EDIT**: The code below is a solution from user [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) (not from  aschipfl) posted here after the original poster of this answer give me his kindly permission. I was forced to do this because the question is closed and I really wanted to post my code!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize data for first store
set /A max=0, lines=0, store=0

for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%a" neq "THE END" (
      rem Process the next line of this store
      set /A lines+=1
      for %%l in (!lines!) do (
         if not defined line[%%l] (
            rem This store have more lines than previous ones: initialize new line
            for /L %%i in (1,1,!store!) do set "line[%%l]=!line[%%l]! ,"
         )
         rem Append new data to this line
         set "line[%%l]=!line[%%l]!%%a,"
      )
   ) else (
      rem This store ends: get the maximum number of lines
      if !lines! gtr !max! (
         set "max=!lines!"
      ) else (
         rem Enlarge the additional lines of previous stores, if any
         set /A lines+=1
         for /L %%i in (!lines!,1,!max!) do set "line[%%i]=!line[%%i]! ,"
      )
      rem Pass to next store
      set /A lines=0, store+=1
   )
)

rem Output all result lines
(for /L %%i in (1,1,%max%) do echo !line[%%i]:~0,-1!) > output.txt
```

Output:

```
store1:,store2:,store3:
 apple, Tree, Building
 orange, Park, Road
 peach, Pond, peach
 , Bird, store
 , , Grocery
```

Comment: Hey aschipfl, after read this topic I wrote my own answer, but now the question is closed! I really would like to post my solution. Would you give me permission to modify your answer so I can post my own code as a second part edit?

Comment: So I guess you also have a batch solution, @Aacini? of course you may do that, I am really curious now anyway... be aware that I earn your reputation points then...

Comment: You're welcome, @Aacini! the only thing I cannot believe is all the spaces in the output - where do they come from? or is it just a typo? and I'm afraid this fails if `!`s occur in the input file... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can pipe a text file into this PowerShell script. It uses PowerShell's dialect of CSV (which includes quote chars).

```
Begin {
    # corresponds to (untransposed) records
    $records = @()
    # the current record
    $this_record = @()
    # maximum fields of any (untransposed) record
    $max_fields = 0
}
Process {
    If ($_ -eq "THE END") {
        # Append the record to the array.
        $records += ,$this_record

        # Count the maximum number of fields (this will be the number of
        #   records when the data is transposed).
        If ($this_record.Length -gt $max_fields) {
            $max_fields = $this_record.Length
        }

        $this_record = @()
    } ElseIf ($_.Trim() -eq "") {
        # Ignore blank lines.
    } Else {
        # Append the field to the current record.
        $this_record += $_
    }
}
End {
    # Transpose the fields
    $objects = @()
    For ($col=0; $col -lt $max_fields; $col+=1) {
        # ConvertTo-CSV gets object properties. It doesn't implicitly
        #   operate on arrays the way we'd prefer.
        $obj = New-Object PSCustomObject
        For ($row=0; $row -lt $records.Length; $row+=1) {
            # Create property names that sort lexically (zero-padded numbers).
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty `
                          -Name ("{00000}" -f $row) `
                          -Value $records[$row][$col]
        }
        $objects += $obj
    }

    # Convert to CSV, throw away the header
    $objects | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1
}
```

E.g. `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File xpose.ps1 < input.txt` produces:

```
"store1:","store2:","store3:"
"apple","Tree","Building"
"orange","Park","Road"
"peach","Pond","peach"
,"Bird","store"
,,"Grocery"
```

Comment: Please don't encourage _gimmie the codez_ questions like this one. It does nothing but devalue the community and reinforces bad behavior. It is likely that the question will be CV'd or deleted anyway.

Comment: @Matt, I consider the question posed legitimate, even if the OP is being lazy. How does one transpose data? It was an interesting problem.

Comment: Thanks Mojo and Anthony Stringer for your help in such a short time.

Comment: @mojo, when I pipe the input file as you mentioned, it throws the below error.

The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:1 char:63

Comment: @Anthony Stringer, it worked. Thanks

Comment: @IceMan, You can redirect it another way: `type input.txt | PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File xpose.ps1`

Answer (score -1):

Here's some code to help you out. Study this!

appendcolumn.bat

```
@echo off

set i=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('more') do (
    call :app !i! %%x
    set /a i += 1
)
exit /b 

:app
set line%1=!line%1!,%2
exit /b
```